# Malware analysis - AntiDebugging - Malware slows down the PC while being debugged

Tags: windows, ollydbg, malware, anti-debugging

As part of my work, I'm debugging a malware found and his behavior is pretty basic after execution:

1. Being executed
2. Decrypt a lot of data from memory and obtain a new PE (from memory)
3. Create a child process in suspended state
4. Dump the new data obtained into the Created child process
5. SetThreadContext
6. ResumeThread

Now one issue i was thinking about, is the fact i dont know what the `EntryPoint` is so i dont know what part of the memory bytes i would change to `EB FE` (JMP < ToSelf >) To be able to debug the process from the start

Once the new process is created and im attaching a debugger to it - OLLYDbg for that case (And the process is on *Pause* state) Pressing `F8 - step over` causing the application to have a huge delay of like 10 seconds untill the Opcode is finished - which makes no sense.
Also if i watch the newly created process on `Sysinternals - ProcessExplorer` I can see that after i press F8 the CPU usage of that process is very high 50-90 for all that time, until the opcode is finished. Which also results in all of the computer to run very slowly

What could cause that? and how would i be able to bypass that?

It does not happen if i dont debug the process.

Comment: Have you changed `EB FE` back to the original opcodes? Instead of pressing  F8 you can try to `Resume All Threads`.

Comment: does attaching to a suspended child process succeed ?

Comment: @ExtremeCoders, Yes ofcourse i remembered.

Comment: @blabb, and yes it succeedes, basically OllyDbg creates a new thread for him self for debugging the process

Comment: oh ollydbg 2.01 resumes the thread from supended state when attaching to a suspended process i dont think that behaviour is a standard behaviour windbg  or ollydbg 1.10 never succeded in attaching to a suspended process  and that is how it should be i think well in such case you **CANT**  resume from your parent thread i think and may cause inconsistent result i would bet

Comment: @blabb 
Nonetheless, i figured what the EntryPoint would be, and i changed the WriteProcessMemory buffer to such that would have a `JMP [_EP]` opcode at the `_EP`. Still it does not explain the lagging of debugging the malware which i cant understand

Comment: How did you figure out the EP? Did you look at the value set by SetThreadContext? Did the parent process only modify the EIP and write a single chunk of data? No other memory writes? No other modifications? It might be detecting you're debugging it and handles that in another context, we need more info to suggest relevant techniques.

Comment: @NirIzr, i took all the data written, all the chunks one by one and re-created the PE as is.. in IDA i could figure what the EP was and use it that way

Comment: Then it's worth making sure `SetThreadContext` changes the EIP to the same value you're looking at. it's not too uncommon to have malware unpack a PE and use a different Entry Point than the one in the PE.

Comment: @NirIzr
Its true that it is common, but even if it was packed, i was looking at the `pre-unpacked` version of the malware, which means regadless of whats happening next, i should have been on the right entry point, and it does seem like the real entry point